# kubernetes pods http: TLS handshake error from x.x.x.x:38676: EOF

Tags: kubernetes, cert-manager

When starting `cert-manager` I get the following message

> `TLS handshake error from 10.42.152.128:38676: EOF`

```
$ kubectl -n cert-manager logs cert-manager-webhook-8575f88c85-l4tlw
I0214 19:41:28.147106       1 main.go:64]  "msg"="enabling TLS as certificate file flags specified"  
I0214 19:41:28.147365       1 server.go:126]  "msg"="listening for insecure healthz connections"  "address"=":6080"
I0214 19:41:28.147418       1 server.go:138]  "msg"="listening for secure connections"  "address"=":10250"
I0214 19:41:28.147437       1 server.go:155]  "msg"="registered pprof handlers"  
I0214 19:41:28.147570       1 tls_file_source.go:144]  "msg"="detected private key or certificate data on disk has changed. reloading certificate"  
2020/02/14 19:43:32 http: TLS handshake error from 10.42.152.128:38676: EOF
```

Interestingly there is not pod with that IP

```
$ kubectl get pod -o wide --all-namespaces | grep 128
cert-manager    cert-manager-webhook-8575f88c85-l4tlw             1/1     Running     0          4m56s   10.42.112.128   node002   <none>           <none>
```

Similar error on the `cert-manager` pod

```
E0214 19:38:22.540589       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/ingress-shim "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook \"webhook.cert-manager.io\": Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=30s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout" "key"="kube-system/dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard"
```

I have two `ClusterIssuer`

```
kubectl get ClusterIssuer --namespace cert-manager
NAME              READY   AGE
letsencrypt-prd   True    42d
letsencrypt-stg   True    42d
```

But no certificate yet:

```
kubectl get certificate --all-namespaces
No resources found
```

When I try to request a certificate I get the same error

```
kubectl apply -f mycert.yml                                                                                                                                                                  
Error from server (InternalError): error when creating "cert-wyssmann-dev.yml": Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook "webhook.cert-manager.io": Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=30s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

I am not sure how exactly can I get to the bottom of the problem. I ran [`sonobouy`](https://sonobuoy.io/) to see if this helps me, however test failed on 2 of my 3 nodes.

```
Plugin: e2e
Status: failed
Total: 1
Passed: 0
Failed: 1
Skipped: 0

Failed tests:
Container e2e is in a terminated state (exit code 1) due to reason: Error: 

Plugin: systemd-logs
Status: failed
Total: 3
Passed: 1
Failed: 2
Skipped: 0

Failed tests:
timeout waiting for results
```

For the failing nodes I can see this in the `sonobouy` logs

```
E0214 19:38:22.540589       1 controller.go:131] cert-manager/controller/ingress-shim "msg"="re-queuing item  due to error processing" "error"="Internal error occurred: failed calling webhook \"webhook.cert-manager.io\": Post https://cert-manager-webhook.cert-manager.svc:443/mutate?timeout=30s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout" "key"="kube-system/dashboard-kubernetes-dashboard"
```

Comment: what is the output of kubectl get issuer --namespace cert-manager and kubectl get certificate -o wide --namespace cert-manager ?

Comment: @Arghya Sadhu Updated the description

Comment: What are the steps or docs you followed to install it?

Comment: I am using helm-chart with helm 3. The whole thing was working before I added a third node to the cluster. So I could issue a certificate back in January when I initially setup `cert-manager`

Comment: 10.42.152.128:38676 is the Kubernetes API Server IP and port? So you added new master node? What was the Kubernetes API Server and port when it was working ?Kubernetes API Server IP and port was changed after you added node?

Comment: output of kubectl get pods --namespace cert-manager ? What is the cert manager version?

Comment: Nope I've added a worker node so Kubernetes API Server IP should be the same. Not sure how I can determine the ip of the `kube-apiserver`. Version of `cert-manager` is `0.13`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207878/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-papanito).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really don't need the webhook then one quick way to solve this is to disable the webhook as per [documentation](https://cert-manager.io/docs/installation/compatibility/#disabling-webhook)

Comment: Not sure if I don't need the webhook, but it seems to work without. See also https://github.com/jetstack/cert-manager/issues/2602. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Disabling the webhook is not supported anymore since v0.14.